# jquery date picker is not working with master page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

> jquery date picker is not working while adding in master pages content
>   place holder. getting error - TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a
>   function

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" Runat="Server">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $("input[id$=txtDatepicker]").datepicker({
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true
         });
     });
    </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:TextBox  ID="txtDatepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Use `<%=txtDatepicker.ClientID%>` instead.

Comment: not worked , that also tried @SuprabhatBiswal

Comment: Any error in developer console? If no error found then instead of writing script in head write in body.

Comment: TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: i have not downloaded anything..all code is infront of u...

Comment: As it is, your code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/td9zk9nm/2/ are you including another jquery library somewhere else?  If you view source of your page, do you include the jquery library twice?

Comment: Perhaps try changing the `$` to a hat `^` so that it will work if you haven't set your app to render ids without the extra guff

Answer (score 3):

Use `#txtDatepicker` instead of `input[id$=txtDatepicker]`

```
 $(function () {
            $("#txtDatepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
```